# Displaying a content page as popup in asp.net,using

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup, master-pages

I have a content page(Say.. invoice.aspx) in asp.net application with master pages.

The content page(invoice.aspx) is using a gridview, which displays records from database.

Currently i am  navigating to this page using - Response.redirect("invoice.aspx") and this is working fine.

But i need to display this page as pop-up from calling page, so that this popup invoice can be seen on the top of other pages.

Please help me if this can be done using javascript or some other way.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      function OpenWindow(strChildPageUrl) {
          var testwindow = window.open(strChildPageUrl, "Child", "width=700px,height=650px,top=0,left=0,scrollbars=1");
          testwindow.moveTo(100, 0);
      }

  </script>
```

Comment: if(true)
                {
                    tblSuccessResponse.Visible = true;
                    tblErrorResponse.Visible = false;
                    
                        if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("InvoicePopup"))
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
                            (this.GetType(), "InvoicePopup", "<script language=javascript>javascript:OpenWindow('http://localhost:56941/Invoice.aspx')</script>");

                }

Comment: Did you mean to add this code in the comment to your answer above?

Answer (score 1):

A page popup can be implemented using a div as a container with a different style (opacity, window position, size etc) and has a higher z-index than the rest of the page.

thus basically you need a structure like

```
<div class="overlayOuter"> 
    <div class="overlayInner">
      <!-- external content to be loaded here -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

and now using AJAX you load the `invoice.aspx` page to the inner container and show the container and reduce the opacity of the outer container.

There should be libraries out there that let you do this. you need to explore that on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal popups for the above scenario:

one example can be found here: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/

its easy and not much code you need to write and also can load popup as an iframe so postbacks can be handled without posting back parent page or you can use ajax